# Can I return a variable from a module?

Tags: python, function, variables, import, module

I have written a module in python in which I want to use in another file. Pretty much, a function in the module has 3 variables in it and I want to get one of those variables in the code of a separate file. The code for the module is:

```
def attrib():

    #Code that isnt important to the question

    global name
    name = stats[0:x]

    global strength
    strength = stats[x+1:x+3]

    global skill
    skill = stats[x+4:x+6]
```

and in the file, I want to separate the three variables in different functions,  so that i can assign them to two different characters, like this:

```
import myModule

def nam():
    return (name from the module)

def sth():
    return (strength from the module)

def skl():
    return (skill from the module)

char_1_nam = nam()
char_1_sth = sth()
char_1_skl = skl()
```

First of all, is this even possible, and secondly how can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong data structure. Consider a `class` instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to my comment, try this instead:

```
# FILENAME: attributes.py

class Attributes(object):
    def __init__(self,stats):
        # I don't know how you formed x in your example but...
        self.name = stats[0:x]
        self.strength = stats[x+1:x+3]
        self.skill = stats[x+4:x+6]

# FILENAME: main.py

from attributes import Attributes

atts = Attributes(stats) # wherever they come from
# atts.name = your name
# atts.strenght = your strength
# atts.skill = your skill
```

Unfortunately you haven't included (and likely SHOULDN'T include, since it's presumably very long) the rest of your code, so it's hard to give you more guidance than to look to object-oriented programming to solve the problem. In general I advise programmers to do something like:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,any,atts,you,might,need):
        self.any = any
        self.atts = atts
        # etc ...
```

It looks like your way of pulling your stats is kind of hokey to begin with -- try using tuples to hold distinct data structure rather than grabbing it from a string by index. It's faster and easier to read. Even if you have to do `stats = (stats[0:x], stats[x+1:x+3], stats[x+4:x+6])` you can still refer to them as `stats[0]`, `stats[1]`, and `stats[2]` from now on. Dictionaries (`statsdict = {'name': stats[0:x], ...}`) are even more robust, but probably unnecessary if this is just a way to move data from a string into a class

Answer (score 0):

First of all the best advice is to a "class" instead of a "function".
Even Though  if you want to use a function to handle this problem.
Here is my solution....

```
#In the module1

variable1 = some value 
variable2 = some value

def get_variable1():
   return variable1 

def get_varable2():
   return variable2

#In the module2

variable1 = get_variable1()
variable2 = get_variable2()
```

By this way You access the variables from another module with functions. but it will be a pain if you wanna access multiple variables because you have to define functions for each variable.

So the best advice is to use an class and by this you will also get the benefits of Object Oriented Programming